# how do i build a JDBC connection url from this XML connection data?

Tags: database, eclipse, oracle, jdbc

I'm connecting to an Oracle database with SQL Developer, the connection data was provided to me in XML form.  I used the "Import Connection Descriptor" feature in SQL Developer and I can connect just fine.  The XML looks like this:

```
<connections>
  <connection>
    <ConnectionType>JDBC</ConnectionType>
    <DeployPassword>false</DeployPassword>
    <user>user1</user>
    <ConnectionName>ccddda</ConnectionName>
    <URL>CCDDDA, CCDDD10A, CCDDD10A.ABCDEF.ABC</URL>
    <RaptorConnectionType>Oracle</RaptorConnectionType>
    <JdbcDriver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</JdbcDriver>
    <PWD>
      <![CDATA[01AB001AB001AB001AB001AB001AB01234]]>
    </PWD>
    <ORACLE_JDBC_TYPE>thin</ORACLE_JDBC_TYPE>
    <PREVIOUS_NAME>ccddd2_11</PREVIOUS_NAME>
  </connection>
</connections>
```

The problem is, I'm trying to create a database connection using the JPA perspective > Datasource Explorer in Eclipse.

My question is, how do I derive the JDBC values from the XML needed to establish the connection?  The dialog is asking for the following:

```
Select a database manager: Oracle
JDBC driver: Oracle 10 - Oracle Thing Driver Default
SID: db /* selected by default */
Host: ?
Port Number: 1521 /* selected by default */
User name: ? /* I assume it's user1 */
Password: ?
Default Schema: ?
Catalog: User /* selected by default */
```

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks, Rob

Comment: Did you look in the connection properties dialog for CCDDDA in Oracle SQL Developer?  It shows the Hostname, Username. Default schema might be the username.  Can't help you with the password ;-)

Comment: In SQL Developer the connection properties are "Connection Type: TNS", "Network Alias: CCDDDA, CCDDD10A, CCDDD10A.ABCDEF.ABC". No other info to be seen. :( I'm guessing this network alias must be pointing to the info I need somehow, by I've never seent his sort of thing before. I'm rather stumped.

Comment: Look in your TNSNAMES.ORA file, but first just try: host: CCDDDA, User: user1, password: <you know>, schema: user1

Comment: Ah!  The TNSNAMES.ORA is where the network alias is configured.  I found the hostname there, but still don't have it working yet.  If you make your "Look in your TNSNAMES.ORA file" comment an answer, I'll mark it as "correct answer".  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in these locations:

- Oracle SQL developer connection properties
- The TNSNAMES.ORA file